# Place To get EULA and Other Legalese For Software?

Tags: language-agnostic

I was curious if anyone out there has experience getting the necessary legal documents (user agreements, privacy policies, disclaimers, etc.) for a small software business.  For example if you just want to have a software 'company' that sells a few piece of software that you have written, are there cheap solutions for something small scale like that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Micro-ISV: From Vision to Reality](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596013), Bob suggests [MegaDox.com](http://www.megadox.com/index.php/search/?for=Software+Licence++) and [Soft14.com](http://www.soft14.com/upload/software_000039.htm)

Comment: Thanks for response, the mentioned links are all what you need if you want to prepare a simple EULA. (Lawyer up if you need anything more).

Answer (score 1):

Stationery stores will sell standard boiler plate contracts.
For software specific stuff most companies just copy the ones from bigger companies and change the name!

Comment: Are there any I.P. concerns associated with doing this?

Comment: Answer to my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715761/is-eula-itself-copy-protected

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions by others in other answers are probably fine if you intend to stay small scale, but if your intent is grow, and particularly if you might want to have someone else invest money in the business, then it makes sense to invest in a lawyer, one who has experience in software.  It doesn’t have to cost a lot if you can develop a relationship with someone interested in working with you for the long run and not running up fees on those basic documents.

By the way, either route you go, it makes sense to read the documents and make sure they fit what you’re actually doing.  If you post a boilerplate privacy policy that says you do x, y and z with customer data, but in fact you do a, b and c instead, you’re creating more potential legal troubles than you’re solving.

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing the waters for a crowd funded project to develop user-friendly EULAs.  The EULAs themselves would be developed like open source.  If a user encounters one of these "open" EULAs, then the user can feel better about agreeing it because

1. it's been reviewed by an open process, and
2. you might encounter this same EULA over and over, so you don't have to read it every time.

https://sites.google.com/a/x2xroads.com/nutshell/open-eula

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been looking for the same info as the OP and found a great book which includes standard agreements for software companies which you may use as is or modify with the help of a lawyer.

```
The IT/Digital Legal Companion: A Comprehensive Business Guide to Software, 
Internet, and IP Law Includes Contract and Web Forms

By: Gene K. Landy; Amy J. Mastrobattista 
Publisher: Syngress
Print ISBN-10: 1-59749-256-6
Print ISBN-13: 978-1-59749-256-0
```

It also includes sections explaining issues that you need to consider for different aspects of you software business in regard to contracts, privacy and intellectual property.